# Scala way to write 'foo["bar"]' of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scala

This is very basic question i guess but how can I access a class member by using variable?
What I wanna achieve is something like this.

//Scala

```
class Foo {
  var sample:String = _
  var sample2:String = _
}
//in another Class
val foo = new Foo()
val key = bar match {
  case "something" => "sample"
  case _ => "sample2"
}
//want to access foo.sample or foo.sample2 by using key variable.
```

Which is written as `foo[key]` in JavaScript

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean `foo.sample` / `foo.sample2` ?

Comment: @Shadowlands Yes That's right. the point is I want to use a variable for the part of member name `sample` or `sample2`

Comment: Short of using reflection I don't think so. You could perhaps store the Foo values you need to access this way as entries in a Map, with the field names as keys, but that can be ugly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the javascript semantic (like access members by name), take a look at `Dynamic`-trait.

With `Dynamic` you can do things like:

```
class MyDynamic extends Dynamic {
  var map = Map.empty[String, Any]

  def selectDynamic(name: String) =
    map get name getOrElse sys.error("method not found")

  def updateDynamic(name: String)(value: Any) {
    map += name -> value
  }
}

scala> val d = new MyDynamic
d: MyDynamic = MyDynamic@7711a33f

scala> d.foo
java.lang.RuntimeException: method not found

scala> d.foo = "blah"
d.foo: Any = "blah"

scala> d.foo
res56: Any = "blah"
```

You can call your methods by name:

```
scala> d.selectDynamic("foo")
res54: String = foo
```